# FontAwesome version 3 vs. 4 icon rendering performance

Tags: html, css, icons, google-chrome-devtools, font-awesome

The [FontAwesome](http://rtawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome) authors say that icon rendering can be up to 30% faster in version 4. I'm wondering about the details of that number.

1. Is it consistently 30% faster? Is it ever slower?
2. Is this result cross browser? Any difference with mobile?
3. Is the speed improvement solely due to the `icon-` to `fa fa-` class name change?

To address these questions, I'd like to benchmark icon rendering speed. I'm made the following JSFiddle and am pretty familiar with browser dev tools (Chrome in particular), is that what one uses? http://jsfiddle.net/timrpeterson/Q5TA5/2/

What part of Chrome dev tools would I look? I assume where [paint speed](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/timeline) is measured?

```
<div>

<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <h3> v4.0.3</h3>
       <i class='fa fa-comment'></i>
       <i class='fa fa-envelope'></i>
</div>
<hr>
<div>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <h3> v3.2.1</h3>
 <i class='icon-comment'></i>
 <i class='icon-envelope'></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Although not an adequate answer, I'd say most performance improvements have larger impacts on mobile devices, since they are slower to begin with. E.g. 100ms -> 50ms and 800ms -> 400ms are both a 50% reduction, but the latter will be perceived as bigger (and in absolute numbers it is, too). However, this is general, I say whether this is the case for Fontawesome or CSS-rendering in particular.
2. I'm pretty sure the primary reason for the speedup is that class selectors instead of attribute selectors are used. E.g. `.icon.icon-name` instead of `[class^="icon-"],
   [class*=" icon-"]`.

Unfortunately I cannot answer your other questions. But hopefully this is partly useful.